# Where is the pom.xml file in the MCP folder?

Tags: java, client, minecraft

When I ran the decompile.bat file, it said this at the end:

[ERROR] Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
Press any key to continue...

I have looked through some stuff about this, and it says I need to find a "pom.xml" file and edit it. where is that pom.xml file located?

Article I read:
[Another Maven "Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860989/another-maven-source-option-6-is-no-longer-supported-use-7-or-later)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what are you trying to decompile.

pom.xml would be placed internally in the decompiled war or ear file

Or check the decompile.bat, might be this param inside this script