# MVN is not letting me install JOCL

Tags: java, maven, jocl

I'm currently trying to install the Java bindings of openCL through JOCL. I have followed the steps provided on their site from cloning the two git links to building the native libraries. I haven't followed the steps installing clBLAS and clBLAST since I do not plan on using those libraries. When going to then build the Java libraries with maven, I get this error

[ERROR] error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later.
[ERROR] error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later

Did I miss a step or is their something wrong with JOCL itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Another Maven "Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860989/another-maven-source-option-6-is-no-longer-supported-use-7-or-later)